# beginner attempting to read xml into php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have an xml feed located [here](http://www.phogue.net/feed) that I am trying to read into a php script, then cycle through the `<packages>`, and sum the `<downloads>`.  I've attempted to do this using DOMDocument, but have thus far failed.

the basic method i've been trying to use is as follows

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML('http://www.phogue.net/feed');
$packages = $dom->getElementsByTagName('package');
foreach($packages as $item)
{
    echo $item->getAttribute('uid').'<br>';
}
?>
```

The above code is meant to just print out the name of each item, but its not working.  I am currently getting the following error

**Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /home/a8744502/public_html/userbar.php on line 3**

WORKING CODE:

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->load('http://www.phogue.net/feed/');
$package = $dom->getElementsByTagName('package');
$value=0;

foreach ($package as $plugin) {

    $downloads = $plugin->getElementsByTagName("downloads");
    $download = $downloads->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $authors = $plugin->getElementsByTagName("author");
    $author = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue;
    if($author == "Zaeed")
    {
        $value += $download;
    }
}
echo $value;
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DOMDocument::loadXML()` expects a string of XML. Try `DOMDocument::load()` instead - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php

Keep in mind that to open an XML file via HTTP, you will need the [appropriate wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) enabled.

Comment: hmmm.. ok, so I'm not getting errors now, just a blank screen :s  http://zaeed.uphero.com/userbar.php.   I've got no idea what you mean by the appropriate wrapper btw

Comment: I got it working...  <package> does have a uid attribute. i'll update my post with the working code

Comment: @Matt Oops, I was wrong about being able to traverse DOMNodeList (PHP doc fail). Your original code was trying to echo a `uid` *attribute* of `<package>` which does not exist. There is a child node though.

Comment: One last quick question.. I've seen examples where you have  www.example.com/phpscript.php%variablehere
or some version of that.. How is that done?

Comment: @Matt You mean like `phpscript.php?variable=something`? If so, look at the `$_GET` superglobal.

Comment: sweet.. got it going.. Thanks for all your help Phil

Answer (score 1):

You have a open parenthesis at the beginning of your echo.